# MySQL insert into table not inserting all fields

Tags: mysql

I have 2 existing tables in a MySql  DB. The tables have identical structures. I want to copy data from table to another.

```
insert into `Table1`
select * from Table2
where department = "engineering"
```

the above code seemed to work and it copied the data correctly except for 1 column. The "department" column did not copy over so it was blank. All the other fields seemed to copy over correctly for all of the records.

What can be causing this? As I mentioned both tables have identical structures, same number of columns and everything...

Any ideas?

Note:I just realized that there are actually 2 columns that are not copying over. The "department" and "Category" fields come over blank. So basically when I am inserting the data from table 2 into table 1, 12 out of 14 columns are successfully copied over but then there are 2 columns that remain blank.

[Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaoMZ.png) is the DESCRIBE of Table1 and Table2

[image]

The only difference I can see when I do a Describe on both tables  is that the 2 fields in question have a data type of enum (.....) but they have differences in between the parenthesis. Could this be causing the issue and if so is there a simple way around it? I'm thinking I might have to do an update query after I do the initial insert that will bring in the "department" and "category" fields from table 2 into table 1 by joining in the ID field.

Comment: What do you see if you run `select * from Table2 where department = "engineering"`?

Comment: Are the columns in the same order in the two tables?

Comment: Post the output of: describe table1 and describe table2

Comment: Generally good to specify the column order as @Barmar is correct.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I get the same 357 records that get copied over when I use my insert code with the "department" & "Category" fields populated but once I use my code to insert all the records into table 1 all the fields get populated into table 1 except for those 2 "department" & "Category"

Comment: @RobertRozas Yes the columns of the 2 tables are in the same order. they have identical structure.

Comment: @Barmar Yes the order is the same.

Comment: @RobertRozas Sorry I was responding to Barmar earlier but I went ahead and posted the DESCRIBE of tbl1 and tbl2 and I did notice that the 2 columns in question have a type of enum with differences in between the parenthesis. I am guessing that this is what is causing the issue. I am going to read up on the enum type now as I am new to MySql and not sure what it means. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: FYI, it would be better if you posted the result of `show create table <tablename>` as plain text. Images like that are hard to read, and even harder to copy and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> If you insert an invalid value into an  `ENUM` (that is, a string not
>   present in the list of permitted values),  the empty string is
>   inserted instead as a special error value.

Read about [`ENUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).

Comment: Because I just happened to come across a similar situation today, I'll also add on that despite the fact that the docs go on to say `If an ENUM column is declared NOT NULL, its default value is the first element of the list of permitted values.`, if you explicitly pass `NULL` to a `NOT NULL` ENUM, you still get the empty string, not the expected (expected to me, at least) default value. So there is apparently a difference between passing no value (passing `NULL`), and not passing a value. Please rebut if you feel this is false.